# (JS) Как добавить элементы в массив?

Tags: javascript, массивы

Есть такой код:

```
users = Sever.GetUsers();
for ( i = 0; i < users.length; i++)
{
name = Server.GetName(users[i]);
Console.log(name); //ВасяПетяСашаРома
}
```

выводит имена пользователей без разделителей: ВасяПетяСашаРома. 
Как добавить эти имена в массив, чтобы было:

```
arr = ["Вася","Петя","Саша","Рома"]
```

**?**

Comment: `arr = users.map(u => Server.GetName(u));`

Comment: к сожалению, пример выше не работает для меня

Comment: А `Server.GetName` - это что?) Если оттуда изначально прилетает такая строка, нужно смотреть, что происходит в его коде...

Comment: Кто удалил комментарий про моего компьютерного гномика? Злая колдунья Арахна?

Comment: Функция прописана в движок, который работает с JavaScript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте так

```
let name =[];
users = Sever.GetUsers();
for ( i = 0; i < users.length; i++)
{
  name.push(users[i].name);
}

console.log(name);
```

Comment: Минус может кто-нибудь объяснит, буду благодарен